# kindle fire tablet not showing install option from play store app,it's showing device not compatiable eith the version

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console

kindle fire tablet not showing application install option from play store, the phone model is ONA19TB002, I used minversion 14 and maximum version 29 but tab not showing install option from play store app, have to want to enable in play store console?

[image]
[image]

Comment: amazon devices (so, kindles) do not have the google play store installed. They have their own amazon appstore service and if you're publishing the app for kindle you must do so in in the amazon developer console (not google)

Comment: also, the ONA19TB002 is not an amazon kindle device, but from some "Onn" manufacturer (not Amazon)

Comment: Thanks to response, may know the reason?

Comment: but play store showing not compatiable of installation may know the reason above problem